# AWS EC2 and build-essential

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I am trying to compile Node.js on Amazon EC2, but I can't even install "build essential". Where's the problem?

Thanks.

---

```
sudo yum install build-essential
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
(...)
No package build-essential available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

---

```
./configure
Checking for program g++ or c++          : not found 
Checking for program icpc                : not found 
Checking for program c++                 : not found 
error: could not configure a cxx compiler!
```

**could not configure a cxx compiler!**

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`build-essential` is a package that resides in `aptitude` (Debian), not in Yum (RHEL).  Maybe you should rephrase your question to provide more information about the core issue--i.e., installing EC2 tools?

---

The (rough) equivalent of the `build-essential` meta-package for yum is:

```
yum install make glibc-devel gcc patch
```

Comment: Yes, please. I just edited my question.

Comment: Updated with a rough equivalent to the Debian meta-package.

Comment: `yum groupinstall "Development Tools"` is a better match, I think.

Comment: Unfortunately (or fortunately?), you'll end up installing a ton of packages that you won't likely need.  Although if you have the time and space to spare, this will save you a lot of time on future compiles.

Answer (score 30):

Its important enough to make this more complete alternative a separate entry:

```
yum groupinstall "Development Tools"
```

Comment: yes, this is the official answer from aws: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/compile-software.html

Answer (score 28):

I'm assuming that you are building node.js, as I had the same problem.  I think the one you are missing is:

```
yum install gcc-c++
```

But you might need more than that one after you get past the first part.

Comment: This fixed it for me. Using node (installing packages) on an AWS Amazon Linux instance, thanks!

Comment: Fixed it for Node V12. Thanks !

Answer (score 5):

In addition to gcc-c++, I also needed to install the development packages for openssl:

```
yum install openssl-devel
```

After that was installed I could then compile and install node.js successfully per http://nodejs.org/#download